# Java - set custom commands for inputs on run

Tags: java, input

With `String[] args`, I can get input on run, But how to set custom parameter for each input like:

`-c` for cat name, `-d` for dog name

so that I can run `java abc.jar -c myCat -d myDog` or `java abc.jar -d myDog -c myCat`